# Visual Studio Source Control Explorer access denied

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

Recently I have been working on a project and have been waiting to publish it to Azure. Before I was able to do this my local user account on my machine was changed. Now when I try to add the project solution to the solution control explorer I get "access to path [old username]/my documents/projects is denied." I have the project copied from the old user account onto the new one I am using. I opened from this location, but it still seems to reference the old path. How do I change this and/or what settings do I need to change?

I have uploaded the project into the source control explorer for the project, and the rest of the team can view it. It is possible to re-load the project from here and create a new work space mapping on the new local account? If so how can I do this?

I managed to get it moved by doing the following, thanks jessehouwing for the push in the right direction.

1. Closed Visual Studio
2. Went to old account, copied project directly to the C drive
3. Went to the new account, opened the project from there
4. Deleted mapping referenced in the picture in jessehouwing's answer
5. Created new mapping under a different name, because even though the old one was removed, there was still a naming conflict (I have no clue)
6. Mapped the source control and local folder from scratch

Comment: The edit was after playing around more with the suggestion from jessehouwing. Thanks, but I need a bit more detailed instruction, as VS 2013 is new to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will have to change your workspace mapping. If the Source Control Explorer allows you, you can open the Workspace dropdown (in the toolbar) and edit the current mapping.

If the Source Control Explorer doesn't allow you due to Access Denied errors, you can also use the commandline utility `tf.exe` to remove them.

```
  tf workspaces /remove
```

And then create a new one through the UI or also from the commandline using

```
  tf workspace /new 
  tf workfold /map
```

I'm re-using an old picture here, step 4 should be to fix the paths in the Workspace folders list on the bottom of the dialog :).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This sounds like what I need. I am new to Visual Studio 2013 however, and am having trouble finding where this toolbar with the work space you mentioned is. I think I see it, but it only lists my machine name. I will edit the question with the new information.

Comment: Added picture. Does this help?

Comment: yes, I see that, only when I hit OK it gives the access denied error. I guess I need to use command line. I have the command line running, only tf is not a recognizable command.

Comment: Just wanted to update you. I was playing around for quite some time with your recommendations and figured it out. Thanks so much for your help. I will update question with what I did.

Comment: I was having a similar issue with VS Community 2015, and kept getting "Access denied" errors in Visual Studio. In addition to the `tf workspaces /remove` command, I had to delete the folder in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Team Foundation Local Workspaces` to fix those errors.

Comment: What if the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Team Foundation Local Workspaces` directory does not exist... I can't delete workspaces in VS, `tf is not a recognizable command`, and I don't have the folder that @ScottWeldon mentions, which appears in the error dialog popup...

Comment: @Zack that really depends on your VS version and TFS version. IT sounds at least that you're not running `tf` from a Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt.

Comment: @jessehouwing you are right, I was trying to run from cmd. I got it to work when I ran VS as administrator though, so I'm thinking that it was actually a permissions issue *creating* that folder, and not necessarily *using* that folder...

Answer (score 0):

This is still happening in 2022 and below are steps we have resolved this "Access Denied" in visual studio (2019 in our case) for Azure DevOps Server.

- Open visual studio command line and run the command;
- tf workspace /delete “WORKSPACE_NAME;OWNER”
- Open folder **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Team Foundation Local Workspaces** and delete anything folder inside
- Verify **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Team Foundation Local Workspaces**
  folder has    the user you are logged into the machine as full access
- Go back into    Visual Studio and reestablish your workspaces and
  perform a get    latest