# Error in accessing TFS in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I've been trying to access a TFS in Visual Studio 2012. But each and every time it is giving me an error as shown below:

[image]

I've tried all the available solutions in the internet but haven't been able to solve it. The credentials I've entered to get access are also correct. Please suggest some way out.

Now I've found out that the folder Microsoft Team Foundation Local Workspaces has not been created. Is it the root cause of this issue? Do I have to reinstall Visual Studio 2012?

Right now I am getting this error:

[image]

I have also tried to access tf.exe but I am still unable to manage the workspace (create a new one), as it is showing the same message as shown in the first image. Please help!

Comment: What version of TFS?  If 2015, can you access the web portal of TFS?  Have you tried reinstalling VS?

Comment: No @chief7 its Visual Studio 2012. I haven't reinstalled it. Does it solve the issue?

Comment: Does your user account have enough rights on the c drive to create folders? I have seen many cases where corporate security does NOT allow the local user profiles to manipulate the c drive.

Comment: No @Paul Swetz , I am not able to create folders in C drive

Comment: There is your problem. Move your workspace onto the D drive or whatever you have that you DO have the rights to create folders on.

Comment: Also give a try with this tool Team Foundation Sidekicks: http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure you can access the web portal of TFS. Enter http://yourserver:8080/tfs in IE and login in successfully.

If this can be achieved, please double check the permission of your account. Make sure you have enough rights. Then try to run VS in Administrator mode and try it again.

Also try to [delete VS and TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) and restart VS.

**Update**

If the Source Control Explorer doesn't allow you create workspace due to Access Denied errors, you can also use the commandline utility **tf.exe** to remove them.

```
  tf workspaces /remove
```

And then create a new one through the UI or also from the commandline using

```
  tf workspace /new 
  tf workfold /map
```

More details please refer this question:[Visual Studio Source Control Explorer access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998649/visual-studio-source-control-explorer-access-denied)

Comment: Yeah I tried out all your ways @Patrick-MSFT ...I am able to login also, and I've cleared the cache also as instructed in the link you have provided. But no solution!

Comment: If the Source Control Explorer doesn't allow you create workspace due to Access Denied errors, you can also use the commandline utility **tf.exe** to remove them.  More details, please refer my update

Comment: Hi @Patrick-MSFT , I am getting an error in tf.exe, "Option remove requires a value". Could you please suggest how can I overcome this?

Comment: Why you are not able to create folders in C:\ drive? Could you use a Administrator account or add your account  to the Administrator group of your desktop computer. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands

Comment: No I don't have any administrator account and also I am unable to add my account to the Administrator group. @Patrick-MSFT can you suggest me one thing? Can this issue be resolved if I uninstall and reinstall Visual Studion in my machine again?

Comment: Seems not, if clear cache is  not helpful. Uninstall and reinstall  VS probably also can't solve the issue. It seems more related to your  fault  workspace. Either to have enough permissions to access the workspace or delete the workspace and create a new one on other Drive such as D:\ will solve the issue.

Comment: does getting permission for the Program Data folder solve the issue, @Patrick-MSFT?

Answer (score 0):

From your Team Explorer window at the home tab you should see solutions tab on the bottom, in there you will have a workspace named. Click that (manage workspace in dropdown that displays) (or if one isn't listed hit 'new'). From there either add a new workspace or edit the existing, on the next window change the local folder to a location you have read/write access to.[image]

Comment: Hi @Paul Swetz I tried this out as well but again it is giving up the same issue while I am trying to change the workspace

Comment: Hi @Paul Swetz, whenever I am trying to add that folder as my new workspace, it is giving me the same error and not allowing to update the workspace