# Fix access path to Team Foundation in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I created a new project and a repository on VSTS. When I tried to check it in, I'm getting the following error message.

Looks like it's trying to access the wrong folder under the wrong profile. "Owner" was a temporary account I had created while I was setting up my computer. Since then I deleted it.

It should be looking under my profile. How do I fix this? Whatever I click on this dialog is giving me an error. Is there a file that I can edit to fix this?

[image]

This is the error I get when I click Advanced:
[image]

When I try to manually configure my workspace, this is the error I got:
[image]

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar problem was [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/637c0bb1-328e-49a7-9928-4ce9005b6945/access-to-the-path-cprogramdatamicrosoft-team-foundation-local?forum=tfsversioncontrol) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998649/visual-studio-source-control-explorer-access-denied). Maybe you have to check permissions of current user to folders on your errors or create server workspace:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response but when I tried to set up my work space manually, I got an error -- see the last image in original post.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion fixed the problem!